# jquery подключен первым, а скрипт не выполняется

Tags: jquery

Использую скрипт для перехода по якорю

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 800);
return false; 
}); 
});
```

Он подключается после jquery, но при этом выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Локально на компе все работает, ошибка появляется при загрузке на хостинг
Куда копать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

После очистки кэша все заработало